Business and Life events in Salesforce not showing component even with permissions

Hi, i have tried to give all access to this components comming from, object permissions to life events, person life events, Busines Milestones but component is not showing. I even added the related list to the page layout as documentation says but still having the same outcome. Is there something im missing? any permission set or license? i do have FSC licence and permission sets.

So we finally got the answer. You have to activate chatter in profile system settings.
